# Will Jinns be with humans in the paradise and Hell?

Tags: jannah, jinn, jahannam

To the best of my knowledge, Jinns have options to commit sin or not (like humans). As a consequence, they'll go to the Jannah (heaven) or hell based on their good and bad deeds. As a result, my question is that:

Will Jinns be with human in the same Jannah or hell?

Answer (score 2):

Bismillah,

You mentioned a very good point at the beginning of your question. Jinns can obey or disobey the commands of Allah (SWT). **For the disbelievers (Kuffar) among the Jinn, they will be in Hell** والعياذ بالله

Allah (SWT) says in Surat **Al-A'raaf** ([#179](http://quran.com/7/179))
[image]

And in Surat **Hud** ([#119](http://quran.com/11/119))
[image]

So, there is no doubt that the disbelievers (Kuffar), whether among Humans or Jinns, will enter Hell. For the sinners, Allah (SWT) will judge fairly, if He wishes to forgive them, He (SWT) will forgive.

Now, for the believers among the Jinns, the **majority** of the scholars have said that they will be admitted to Paradise according to various verses in the Qur'an that talked about Paradise, like this one in Surat Ar-Rahman ([46-47](http://quran.com/55/46-47))

[image]

**Allah knows best!**

Comment: I appreciate your nice presented verse. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 0):

They will be together in hell though I haven’t came across any verse about heaven.[image]